# How to solve npm bower install error?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

```
ipriyan@iPriyan:~$ sudo npm install -g bower
```

Hi, I tried to install bower by above command but i'm getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! file /home/ipriyan/.npm/node-uuid/1.4.3/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/ipriyan/.npm/node-uuid/1.4.3/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ipriyan/npm-debug.log
```

How to solve this issue?
I am using 14.04 Ubuntu 64 bit operating system
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `npm cache clean`?

Comment: No i have installed node and npm as new. Do you recommend to cache clean and try?

Comment: There is an empty `package.json` in your cache directory, as indicated by the error message. That is why I suggested cleaning the cache.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with your `package.json` file. Please double check it. You can also use this command to fix it:

```
node package.json
```